# Flyspell check entire document upon opening

Tags: flyspell

I have enabled Flyspell in .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

When I open a document and start typing, typos will be underlined. However, when I close and reopen the document, the same error will not be underlined unless I select the word or move over it with the cursors.

**Q:** Is there a way to recheck (non-interactively) the whole document and underline errors upon opening a document with Flyspell?

Comment: `flyspell-buffer`

Comment: If you work this into an answer I can accept that and close this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-x flyspell-buffer`

Or insert `(flyspell-buffer)` into `org-mode-hook`